# Updating a Django project from 1.2 to 1.3, manage.py not working properly

Tags: python, django

I decided I wanted to update my Django 1.2 project to Django 1.3 to take advantage of the new static files mechanisms. I deleted my old version of Django, and followed the documentation's instructions for installing the development version from svn.

The changes seem to have taken. That is, python -c "import django; print django.get_version()" yields "1.3 alpha 1 SVN-14686". Yet, I can't seem to take advantage of 1.3 features in my old project. If I do "python manage.py collectstatic --help" I get "Unknown command: 'collectstatic'".

I tried creating a fresh project and doing the same thing, and the collectstatic command worked. I dug into django.core.management, but can't really make a lot of sense of it. The docstring for get_commands() mentions:

> The dictionary is cached on the first
>   call and reused on subsequent calls.

Maybe this is totally irrelevant, but I wonder if my problem has something to do with caching (that is, an old version of the command dictionary is cached, which doesn't have the new 1.3 commands?). Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you get if you do a `python manage.py shell` first and then check the version?

Comment: @Ignacio The version is still 1.3.

Comment: Try this: `$ python manage.py shell` then `import sys; print sys.path` and then compare with the output for the brand new project. I suspect that the old project is calling the old version of django somehow.

Comment: @Jordan I just tried this. Except for their first entries (which corresponded to the current working directory) the paths were identical.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In order to use a management command, you need to add the application that provides it to `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py. From [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/):

> First, you’ll need to make sure that `django.contrib.staticfiles` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

That should make the command available.

Comment: Yikes, how did I mis this?! Thanks so much.